# Constructing a completion of a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know only one way to construct a completion of a measure space whose argument starts from showing that $\{A\cup B: B \text{ is a subset of null set and } A \text{ is a measurable set}\}$ is a sigma-algebra.

However, in wikipedia, another construction is stated.

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $P$ be the set of subsets of null sets.
>
> Let $\Sigma^*$ be the sigma-algebra generated by $P\cup \Sigma$.
>
> Define $\mu^*(E)=\inf \{\mu(A):E\subset A\in \Sigma\}, \forall E\in \Sigma^*$
>
> Then $\mu^*$ is complete.

I don't know how to prove that $\mu^*$ is a measure. I don't know where to start.

Please help.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question?

Comment: @Michael When i posted my previous question, i was curious to know the *uniqueness* of the completion. After i posted, i tried to prove the existence of completion following the way illustrated in wikipedia. But i couldn't prove it. This post is about existence and the past post is about uniqueness

Comment: @Michael I see these two are very different. Your answer in the past post assumes that $\{A\cup B: A\in \Sigma , B\in P\}$ is exactly the sigma algebra generated by $\Sigma \cup P$. This is the consequence of *axiom of countable choice*. However, if you directly prove that $\mu^*$ is a measure in this post, it means that *ACC* is not required for existence of completion.